# VALUE ERROR: x, y, and format string must not be None. (error while plotting hysteresis loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

With the low cycle fatigue data, I'm trying to plot the Hysteresis loop. But I'm getting the following error:

```
[ -52.18297297  -45.58565338   16.9913185  ... -354.53630032 -295.50857248
-155.42088911]
[-0.01229182 -0.00891753  0.02256744 ... -0.33507242 -0.31283728
-0.24790212]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f:\I2M\LCF\Ep1_camp4_P4_TTH650 06-9-21 11 01 24\ep1_camp4_P4.py", line 16, in <module>
plt.plot(strain, Sigma, color = 'k')
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2840, in plot
return gca().plot(
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1743, in plot
lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 273, in __call__
yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 379, in _plot_args
raise ValueError("x, y, and format string must not be None")
ValueError: x, y, and format string must not be None
```

And here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.style.use(['science','no-latex'])

x = np.loadtxt('F:\\I2M\\LCF\\Ep1_camp4_P4_TTH650 06-9-21 11 01 24\\data_1.csv',unpack = True, 
skiprows = 2, usecols = 2, delimiter = ',')
y = np.loadtxt('F:\\I2M\\LCF\\Ep1_camp4_P4_TTH650 06-9-21 11 01 24\\data_1.csv',unpack = True, 
skiprows = 2, usecols = 3, delimiter = ',')
stress = (x*1000)/28.27   #N/mm^2 = MPa
length = len(stress)
length = len(y)

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
Sigma = print(stress[0:length:10]) #stress
strain = print(y[0:length:10])


plt.plot(strain, Sigma, color = 'k')

plt.show()
```

Data contains many rows. So I used some commands to access only particular values from the row

Comment: Did you check if x or y has a `None` element?

Comment: What is `strain`?  its actual value, not what you think it should be!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
Sigma = print(stress[0:length:10]) #stress
strain = print(y[0:length:10])
```

what you want plausibly is to sample every 10th data point, but what you get is … nothing or, from the point of view of Python: `None`, so that later your stack trace informs you that `x, y, and format string must not be None`.

Why this happens, and how you solve the problem?

When you make an assignment, the *value* of the expression on the right is saved and you can use the name on the left to use it later, so you save, e.g., the *value* returned by `print(y[0:length:10])` to use it later under the name `strain`, but `print()` is used for its side effects (i.e., showing a bunch of characters on your terminal) and the value that is returned in these cases is by default `None`, not what was shown on your terminal.

If I have understood your intentions, you should omit the two lines above and just use

```
plt.plot(x[0:length:10], y[0:length:10], color='k')
```

A side note, you have

```
length = len(stress)
length = len(y)
```

but you read them from the same file, one assignment should be enough…

---

PS

```
x, y = np.loadtxt('…\\data_1.csv', unpack=1, skiprows=2, usecols=[2,3], delimiter=',')
```